# Disable notifications for Minetime app

Tags: xfce, notification, desktop-apps

I have [minetime](https://minetime.ai/) (latest version) launching to run in background after startup in Xubuntu 18.04. I want to see my calendar, but I don't need the notifications which display 10 minutes before the event.

I can start a config to enable/disable notifications for some applications with [xfce4-notifyd-config](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/xfce4-notifyd-config.1.html) but *minetime* isn't displayed there. The app isn't installed using [apt](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/apt.8.html) or [dpkg](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/dpkg.1.html); I run it directly from */home/user/bin* .